# Comprehensions with nested loop to create set

Tags: set, list-comprehension, nested-loops

**I've to create a set which is the all sum of all combinations of three coins that are dividable by 65.
what I have so far is the following:**

- coins = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]

my code so far:

```
set([x + y + i for x in coins for y in coins for i in coins if (x+y+i)%65])
```

the outcome has to be:

```
set(result) == {65, 130, 260}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to see if the modulus equals zero (there is no remainder left).

```
m = set([x + y + i for x in coins for y in coins for i in coins if (x+y+i)%65==0])

print(m)

>>> {65, 130, 260}
```

Comment: I've already got the answer, but thanks anyway !